# Selenium Python - Finding Elements by Class Name With dynamic parameters

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I was wondering if there is any way to find element by class name if the class name have a static **param** and **dynamic param**, I'll explain:
I got

```
< class="**dataset-selection-dialog-actions** *ng-tns-c139-19*" >
```

the `'dataset-selection-dialog-actions'` is static but `'ng-tns-c139-19'` can be change of any reload page.

can I locate this element without the dynamic **param** ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes why not.

Please use `find_element_by_class_name('dataset-selection-dialog-actions')`

but make sure that it is unique element in **HTMLDOM**.

to check if it is unique or not, use this css selector, `.dataset-selection-dialog-actions`

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css selector` `.dataset-selection-dialog-actions` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.